# JupyterLab Installation Error

Tags: ubuntu, conda, jupyter-lab

Recently I attempted to install jupyter-lab via conda, as directed on the Jupyter [installation page](http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html)

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

I received a link error, highlighted in bold in the below copy-paste of my terminal output. **What should I do next in order to fix and properly install Jupyter-Lab?**

```
daniel@Cerebrate:~$ conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /home/daniel/anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-env-2.6.0            |                0         1017 B  conda-forge
    requests-2.13.0            |           py35_0         815 KB  conda-forge
    send2trash-1.5.0           |             py_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    pyopenssl-16.2.0           |           py35_0          72 KB  conda-forge
    conda-4.3.34               |           py35_0         517 KB  conda-forge
    notebook-5.3.1             |           py35_0         6.6 MB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab_launcher-0.10.5 |           py35_0          24 KB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab-0.31.8          |           py35_1         8.5 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    conda-env:           2.6.0-0       conda-forge
    jupyterlab:          0.31.8-py35_1 conda-forge
    jupyterlab_launcher: 0.10.5-py35_0 conda-forge
    send2trash:          1.5.0-py_0    conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:               4.2.9-py35_0              --> 4.3.34-py35_0 conda-forge
    notebook:            4.2.3-py35_0              --> 5.3.1-py35_0  conda-forge
    pyopenssl:           16.0.0-py35_0             --> 16.2.0-py35_0 conda-forge
    requests:            2.11.1-py35_0             --> 2.13.0-py35_0 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
conda-env-2.6. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 863.48 kB/s
requests-2.13. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:02 386.39 kB/s
send2trash-1.5 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   8.48 MB/s
pyopenssl-16.2 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 206.29 kB/s
conda-4.3.34-p 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:01 458.02 kB/s
notebook-5.3.1 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:04   1.48 MB/s
jupyterlab_lau 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 193.84 kB/s
jupyterlab-0.3 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:05   1.78 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|###################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|###################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
**LinkError: Link error: Error: post-link failed for: conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1**
```

I attempted to remedy the situation by simply reattempting the install (repeating the conda install command into the same terminal )
with "-v" for more verbose errors)

```
daniel@Cerebrate:~$ conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab -v
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/daniel/anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    jupyterlab: 0.31.8-py35_1     conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda:   4.2.0-np111py35_0             --> custom-py35h104c396_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

()

===> UNLINKING PACKAGE: defaults::anaconda-4.2.0-np111py35_0 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3


===> LINKING PACKAGE: defaults::anaconda-custom-py35h104c396_0 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3
  source=/home/daniel/anaconda3/pkgs/anaconda-custom-py35h104c396_0


===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3
  source=/home/daniel/anaconda3/pkgs/jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1


$ /bin/bash -x /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh
==> cwd: /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin <==
==> exit code: 1 <==
==> stdout <==
b''
==> stderr <==
b'+ /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-serverextension enable jupyterlab --py --sys-prefix\n'


An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1'.
LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
<None>

Attempting to roll back.


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: defaults::anaconda-custom-py35h104c396_0 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3


===> REVERSING PACKAGE UNLINK: defaults::anaconda-4.2.0-np111py35_0 <===
  prefix=/home/daniel/anaconda3


An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.3.34
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.34
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.13.0
       root environment : /home/daniel/anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/daniel/anaconda3
       envs directories : /home/daniel/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/daniel/.conda/envs
          package cache : /home/daniel/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/daniel/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.34 requests/2.13.0 CPython/3.5.2 Linux/4.10.0-42-generic debian/stretch/sid glibc/2.24    
                UID:GID : 1000:1000

`$ /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab -v`




    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 499, in run_script
        subprocess_call(command_args, env=env, path=dirname(path))
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 56, in subprocess_call
        output=_format_output(command_str, path, rc, stdout, stderr))
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-x', '/home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 329, in _execute_actions
        run_script(target_prefix, Dist(pkg_data), 'post-unlink' if is_unlink else 'post-link')
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 515, in run_script
        raise LinkError(message)
    conda.exceptions.LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1
    running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
    location of failed script: /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh
    ==> script messages <==
    <None>


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 283, in execute
        pkg_data, actions)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 346, in _execute_actions
        reverse_excs,
    conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1
    running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
    location of failed script: /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh
    ==> script messages <==
    <None>



    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 640, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in _main
        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 80, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 326, in install
        execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not context.quiet)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 174, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 831, in execute_actions
        execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 247, in execute_instructions
        cmd(state, arg)
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 108, in UNLINKLINKTRANSACTION_CMD
        txn.execute()
      File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 299, in execute
        rollback_excs,
    conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.31.8-py35_1
    running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
    location of failed script: /home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/.jupyterlab-post-link.sh
    ==> script messages <==
    <None>
```

Comment: Same problem, but I fixed it after updated my `conda`, see https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-tutorial/issues/21